# Finding the sum of values of objects within arrays using recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to get the sum of tasks completed using recursion. An object represents a team member and they can manage other members.

```js
var team = {
  name: 'Rufus',
  completedTasks: 4,
  manages: [
    {
      name: 'Clara',
      completedTasks: 6,
      manages: [
        {
          name: 'Dana',
          completedTasks: 12,
          manages: []
        }
      ]
    },
   {
      name: 'Charles',
      completedTasks: 19,
      manages: []
    }
  ]
};
```

This is what I have implemented, but I am not getting 41.
4 + 6 + 12 + 19 = 41.
The function is returning 45.

```js
var totalTasks = function (team) {
  
  var sum = 0;
  
  var innerFunction = function(obj) {

  if (obj.manages.length === 0) {
    sum += obj.completedTasks;
    return;
  }

    obj.manages.forEach(function(item) {
      sum += obj.completedTasks;
      innerFunction(item);
    });
  };

  innerFunction(team);

  return sum;
};

totalTasks(team);
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because in your `forEach` loop you add `obj.completedTasks` which has nothing to do with the looped item, and so you are adding the *same* number in every iteration.

Keep the adding limited to only add `obj.completedTasks` once (as the first thing to do), unconditionally. So:

```js
var team = {name: 'Rufus',completedTasks: 4,manages: [{name: 'Clara',completedTasks: 6,manages: [{name: 'Dana',completedTasks: 12,manages: []}]},{name: 'Charles',completedTasks: 19,manages: []}]};

var totalTasks = function (team) {
  var sum = 0;

  var innerFunction = function(obj) {
    sum += obj.completedTasks;
    if (obj.manages.length === 0) return;
    obj.manages.forEach(innerFunction);
  };

  innerFunction(team);
  return sum;
};

console.log(totalTasks(team));
```

It is nicer if you don't manage `sum` as a non-local variable, but just accumulate it recursively:

```js
var team = {name: 'Rufus',completedTasks: 4,manages: [{name: 'Clara',completedTasks: 6,manages: [{name: 'Dana',completedTasks: 12,manages: []}]},{name: 'Charles',completedTasks: 19,manages: []}]};

var totalTasks = team =>
    team.completedTasks + 
    team.manages.reduce((sum, child) => sum + totalTasks(child), 0);

console.log(totalTasks(team));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you wrote:

```js
sum += obj.completedTasks;
```

instead of

```js
sum += item.completedTasks;
```

inside the foreach which means that the outer person's completed tasks is getting added instead of the inner person's.

Regardless, it seemed your function was overcomplicated and could be shortened.

```js
function allTasks (person)
{
    return person.completedTasks + person.manages.map(allTasks).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}
```

```js
var team = {
  name: 'Rufus',
  completedTasks: 4,
  manages: [
    {
      name: 'Clara',
      completedTasks: 6,
      manages: [
        {
          name: 'Dana',
          completedTasks: 12,
          manages: []
        }
      ]
    },
   {
      name: 'Charles',
      completedTasks: 19,
      manages: []
    }
  ]
};

function allTasks (person)
{
    return person.completedTasks + person.manages.map(allTasks).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}

console.log(allTasks(team));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will solve the problem.

```
function totalTasks(item){
  if (item.manages.length){
    return item.completedTasks + item.manages.reduce((sum,item) => sum + totalTask(item), 0 )
  }

  return item.completedTasks
}

totalTasks(team);
```